# Can I restore Samsung Home

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have accidentally disabled Samsung Home (`process.com.sec.android.app.twlauncher`) from my Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830.

Now apps won't open so I can't access settings etc to try to rectify this.

How can I restore the aforementioned `twlauncher`?

Comment: What did you do to disable it? Do you have another launcher installed? Even non-samsung apps fail to open?

Comment: Did you try restart your phone and checked?

Comment: I wanted to install Whatsapp but received a warning that there was not enough memory and apps should be deleted. In my enthusiasm and ignorance I deleted twlauncher. This was not intentional and I was not installing another launcher; so, no launcher no apps, which also means I access nothing. I did try switching off and re-booting, but, as expected, nothing changed and my 'phone is useless.

Comment: Can you not extract `twlauncher` from another system ROM dump found elsewhere and push it across - oh wait, just realized, are you rooted?

Comment: I understand a bit what "rooting" means but I don't believe my phone is rooted. I relied on the operating system not allowing me to delete any installed app  essential to operating the phone. @RyanConrad In my last response I said I had tried switching off and re-booting. _Re-booting_ may have been mis-leading, as I do not know how. I switched off & back on again, but when the phone is starting up, it immediately shows _The app.Samsung Home.......has stopped unexpectedly._ Force close is the only option but the message re-appears & no other functions are available.

Comment: If you deleted twlauncher, you are rooted. you need to sideload a launcher or put twlauncher back in /system/app

Comment: Same phone, same problem. Is your launcher fixed already?
May I ask what did you do so that I can fix mine as well. Thanks

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.... too bad there aren't answers